# Can inductor voltage and capacitor current change abruptly?

Tags: capacitor, inductor

I understand that inductor current and capacitor voltage cannot change abruptly, but can inductor voltage and capacitor current change abruptly?

I have a feeling the answer is no but I cannot explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ideal world, where a capacitor has no series inductance and an inductor has no parallel capacitance, and voltage and current sources can provide voltages and currents with a step-shaped profile, the current into a capacitor and the voltage over an inductor can change abruptly.

Note that the reverse is *not* true: the voltage over a capacitor, and the current through an inductor, can *not* change abrubtly (unless you allow for non-finite currents or voltages, like a Dirac-shaped pulse).

Note that this ideal world is an mathematical abstraction, you can't buy such components.

Comment: Thank you. I am only doing mathematical abstractions at this point of my education, so that's completely fine.

Comment: shouldn't the word "resistor" be replaced with "inductor" in the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: correct. updated.

Answer (score 6):

> but can inductor voltage and capacitor current change abruptly?

Yes, in the context of ideal circuit theory.  Indeed, this is often the case when there is a switch in the circuit.

Mathematically, if the slope of inductor current (capacitor voltage) changes abruptly, the inductor voltage (capacitor current) is discontinuous.

So, for example, consider the case that a charged capacitor, an open switch, and a resistor are in series ([as in problem 2 here](https://ilt.seas.harvard.edu/students/lectures/printablelecture/?PHPSESSID=1c3d8b141d54snatfu17v962j3&lectureID=9644))

At the instant the switch is closed, the voltage across the resistor instantaneously changes from zero to the initial capacitor voltage \$V_0\$.  Thus, the capacitor current discontinuously changes from zero to non-zero and is given by

$$i_C(t) = \frac{V_0}{R}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}} \cdot u(t)$$

where \$u(t)\$ is the [unit step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

The dual of this is an inductor, with non-zero current \$I_0\$, in parallel with a closed switch and a resistor.  At the instant the switch is opened, the current through the resistor changes instantly from zero to the initial inductor current.  Thus, the inductor voltage discontinuously changes from zero to non-zero and is given by

$$v_L(t) = I_0R\;e^{-\frac{tR}{L}} \cdot u(t) $$

In physical circuits, voltages and currents cannot instantaneously change but depending on the characteristic time scale, they can *effectively* change instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I = C*dv/dt.  So a step of voltage on a capacitor (infinite dv/dt) leads to infinite current.  The response to a step of current is 1/C times the integral of the current.  The integral of a step is a ramp, so the capacitor voltage will ramp linearly in response to a step of current. (From whatever initial condition voltage is on it.)

An inductor's response is analogous with current and voltage switched.